# Php-sql result in joomla displayed in question marks

Tags: php, mysql, rsform

I have a simple sql query, in a joomla php server, rs forms pro. The result contains Greek characters. However, the result is displayed in question marks.

```
$sql = "SELECT `FieldValue` FROM `table` where `FieldName` = 'age' and `SubmissionId` =   ".$submissionId."
";


$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 

{ echo
     $row["FieldValue"] ; 
}
```

Result:

??? 20 ???? (question marks should be Greek letters)

I tried using convert as utf8, and it did not work. 
Likewise with

```
 header('Content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8');
header('Content-Type: charset=utf-8');
mysqli_set_charset($con, 'utf8mb4');
```

They did not work either. What else can i do?

```
 $sql = "SELECT CONVERT(`FieldValue` USING utf8) as `FieldValue`
  FROM `table` where `FieldName` = 'age' and `SubmissionId` =   ".$submissionId."";
```

Comment: At StackOverflow, this is where we send everybody with this issue: [UTF-8 all the way through](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through).  If the tips in that page do not help you, please provide more of the details around your database table structure/settings as well as some sample data, so that we can replicate the issue.  If you manage to solve your own issue, please post your solution in a fashion that future researchers will be educated by and award your post with the big green tick to signify that your issue is resolved.

Comment: There is a difference between `mysql_ and `mysqli_` functions.  Don't mix them in your script.

Answer (score 2):

Try doing below stuff if you are using mysql:

after you connect to the mysql, do this query to make sure that you are using UTF8:

```
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
mysql_query("SET CHARACTER SET 'utf8'");
```

Also make sure you are using right encoding in your html head

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
```

If this does not work you can try different character sets for the same.
This [link](https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/mysql-utf8mb4) might help you, Also one suggestion Use Joomla's methods for [query building](https://docs.joomla.org/Selecting_data_using_JDatabase).

Comment: I have tried
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
mysql_query("SET CHARACTER SET 'utf8'");

It is because of the server, not the query. Furthermore, it is a directory inside rs form, in a switch statement-i cannot use html.

Comment: So did you changed server configs ?? Is it working now ?

Comment: No. There is no option for utf8 in the profiles in configuration files, and not working yet.

Comment: Did you tried to run same query in phpmyadmin ?  As while I had same issue I tried above answer and it worked for me. Just to be on same page , When you say profiles configuration file what do you mean ?. Can you put some sample data on which you are not able to run the query ?

Comment: Phpmyadmin shows greek leters normally.
Pro files, it is a component that shows the folders with configuration files.

Comment: Then it will be issue of showing it via php, echoing those characters causing problem , Might be you need to update php.ini file to support the greek characters , You should check default_charset variable in php.ini  file.

Comment: @stsesn please do as much as you can to progress your questions toward a clear resolution.